# Color a cell if it matches any other cell in a Google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I'm trying to use conditional formatting (and maybe the MATCH function?) in a Google Sheet to color any cells from A1 to G10 which have the same contents. For example, if B3 says "Go Seahawks" and so does F5, I would like both of those cells to be colored.

I looked at this question which seemed close ([Conditional formatting cells if their value equals ANY value of another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27345379/conditional-formatting-cells-if-their-value-equals-any-value-of-another-column)), but my formula skills are weak and I couldn't figure out how to make it work the way I want it to. I'd be very appreciative if anyone here can help me figure it out.

Comment: Why did you put an EXCEL tag if your question is exclusively about google-spreadsheet ?

Comment: Check Selfish's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21899516/highlight-cell-if-value-duplicate-in-same-column-for-google-spreadsheet

Comment: Wow, @pnuts, I actually have learned from that, so I did not know it is unnecessary nonsense. Would you care teaching me why you say this?

Comment: @AlissonBezerra, I put the excel tag because the interface suggested it, and because it seemed like the answer to my question could be very similar in Google Sheets as it would be for Excel (if not identical).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MATCH` only operates on a one-dimensional array, so `COUNTIF` is a better approach.

Add a new conditional format to the range `A1:G10`, with a custom formula as follows:

```
=COUNTIF($A$1:$G$10, A1)>1
```

This will highlight any value that occurs in the range more than once.